# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Application' to type 'applicationName.App' error

Tags: c#, wpf, application-name

### Setup:

- Visual studio 2015 Community
- WPF 4.5 application
- MVVM design structure

### Problem:

Error which is causing problems is somehow related to the application naming and also to common casting, however, this error appeared after my attempt to alter the `project properties` on `Visual Studio 2015`. Particularly the `Assembly name` and Default `namespace`. Now I am unable to find the cause and fix it.

Any tips about what would be the right way to proceed?

This error is appearing on the `App.xaml`:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Application' to
>   type
>   'FxConnection.App'.   AppName C:\Users*\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2015\Project1\App.xaml 11

The line in question is:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <viewModels:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
```

I am using `Mvvm light` and its `viewModelLocator` on my project. This error is causing some binding errors when I am trying to use the `Locator` to find the viewmodels.

**EDIT1:**

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="FxConnection.App" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             d1p1:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:FxConnection.ViewModels" 
             xmlns:ds="clr-namespace:FxConnection.Helpers">
    <!-- StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml"-->
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <viewModels:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
            <BitmapImage x:Key="FidelixLogo" CreateOptions="IgnoreImageCache" CacheOption="OnLoad" UriSource="/**/logo.png" />
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="*******" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Deployment.Application;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using FxConnection.Properties;
using FxConnection.Views;
using FxConnection.Views.ProjectView;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading;

namespace FxConnection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            // Handle globally exceptions
#if DEBUG
            //Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(AppDispatcherUnhandledException);
#else
            Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(AppDispatcherUnhandledException);
#endif
            new ProjectDeviceDatabaseView().Show();
            base.OnStartup(e);
            Settings.Default.Reload();
            DispatcherHelper.Initialize();  // allows messenger functionality between threads !
        }

        protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            Settings.Default.Save();
            base.OnExit(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete markup of your App.xaml file as well as the code of the App.xaml.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `App` class in `App.xaml.cs` derives from `System.Window.Application`:

```
public partial class App : System.Window.Application
...
```

Comment: Seem to be in order. Resharper is suggesting: `Base type 'Application' is already specified in other parts`